# Problems adding legend to ggplot2 + ggfortify

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggfortify

I'm having troubles using

```
scale_colour_manual
```

function of ggplot. I tried

```
guide = "legend"
```

to force legend appears, but it doesn't work. Rep code:

```
library(ggfortify)
library(ggplot2)
p  <- ggdistribution(pgamma, seq(0, 100, 0.1), shape = 0.92, scale = 22, 
                     colour = 'red')
p2 <- ggdistribution(pgamma, seq(0, 100, 0.1), shape = 0.9, scale = 5, 
                     colour = 'blue', p=p)

p2 + 
theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
theme(legend.position ="top") +
xlab("Precipitación") +
ylab("F(x)") +
scale_colour_manual("Legend title", guide = "legend", 
                      values = c("red", "blue"), labels = c("Observado","Reforecast")) +
ggtitle("Ajuste Gamma")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `stat_function`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

cols <- c("LINE1"="red","LINE2"="blue")
df <- data.frame(x=seq(0, 100, 0.1))
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x)) + 
stat_function(aes(colour = "LINE1"), fun=pgamma, args=list(shape = 0.92, scale = 22)) +
stat_function(aes(colour = "LINE2"), fun=pgamma, args=list(shape = 0.9, scale = 5)) +
theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
theme(legend.position ="top") +
xlab("Precipitación") +
ylab("F(x)") +
scale_colour_manual("Legend title", values=c(LINE1="red",LINE2="blue"),
                    labels = c("Observado","Reforecast")) +
scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
ggtitle("Ajuste Gamma")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with `ggfortify`.* You can achieve identical results simply using `geom_line()` from `ggplot2` though:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Sequence of values to draw from dist(s) for plotting
x = seq(0, 100, 0.1)

# Defining dists
d1 = pgamma(x, shape=0.92, scale=22)
d2 = pgamma(x, shape=0.90, scale=5)

# Plotting
p1 = ggplot() +
     geom_line(aes(x,d1,colour='red')) + 
     geom_line(aes(x,d2,colour='blue')) + 
     
     theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
     theme(legend.position="top") +

     ggtitle("Ajuste Gamma") +
     xlab("Precipitación") +
     ylab("F(x)") +
     
     scale_colour_manual("Legend title", 
                         guide = "legend", 
                         values = c("red", "blue"), 
                         labels=c("Observado", "Reforecast"))
```

[image: Results figure]

---

* Related question: [Plotting multiple density distributions on one plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025907/plotting-multiple-density-distributions-on-one-plot)